# Getting Error with loading of requirejs and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I am trying a simple demo with requirejs and jquery for AMD. 
Following is my folder structure structure:

```
├── index.html
└── js
    ├── lib
    │   ├── jquery.js
    │   └── require.js
    └── main.js
```

in my index.html file i have the following content:

```
  <head>
    <script data-main="js/main" src="js/lib/require.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="hello">    </div>

  </body>
```

and my main.js file looks like this:

```
define(['lib/jquery'], function ($) {

  $("#hello").html("Wow this works!");

});
```

But when i do, i get an error: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`  in main.js line 3.

What is wrong? I can't understand?

Comment: Have you define to call sjuery library? on your html just call require.js

Comment: Is it possible that `#hello` does not exist at the time of script execution?

Comment: i tried this as well: `require(['lib/jquery'], function ($) {

    $(function(){
          $("#hello").text("Wow this works!");
    });


});` This also gives same error.

Comment: Have you taken a look at [this answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10143493/1004889)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried your example without "$" in first line of main.js and it worked properly.

Fixed **main.js**:

```
define(['lib/jquery'], function () {
     $("#hello").html("Wow this works!");
});
```

Comment: as per my reading of the docs, *define* first takes an array and then values from that array are passed to an anonymous function. Hence I passed $ to that function, whats wrong with my implementation?

Comment: I'm not too sure, but try to `console.log` the parameter of anonymous function - it will return `undefined` (it did that when I was playing your code). So jQuery's `$` was overwriten by undefined variable, and hence no jQuery function were available.

Comment: This just creates an implicit dependency on global object `$`, which sort of defeats the whole purpose of loading jQuery as a module in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

Read this issue: https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/issues/435

My understanding is this is because of how jquery defines itself. It is using a named define call:

```
define( "jquery", [], function () { return jQuery; } );
```

So now, if you require `'lib/jquery'` it won't work. You have to exactly require `'jquery'` for it to work.

**EDIT:**

If you want to put jquery in `lib/` folder and your base url to be the parent folder of `lib/` (`lib/../`) you can use a shim like this:

```
requirejs.config({
  baseUrl: 'js',
  shim: {
    'lib/backbone': {
      deps: ['lib/underscore', 'lib/jquery'],
      exports: 'Backbone'
    },
    'lib/underscore': {
      exports: '_'
    },
    'lib/jquery': {
      exports: '$'
    }
  }
});

requirejs(['lib/jquery'], function($) {
  // use $
});
```

Comment: On [http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html]( http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html), it is clearly stated that;

// THIS WILL NOT WORK
define(['lib/jquery'], function ($) {...});

Comment: If you don't configure requirejs, it will not work. But As you see, I have configured it before requiring it.

Comment: I mean you should not use 'lib/jquery'

Answer (score 0):

```
<script data-main="js" src="js/lib/require.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

is what you want. the `data-main` attribute just points to what should be the root of relative request for it. So you'll need to load in main directly or through an script tag or a `require()` call in an inline script block

Comment: -1. This causes an `Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined` from `main.js`. Also: `data-main` does more than "just points to what should be the root of the relative request to for it". In the OP's example, [it will actually load a script](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#jsfiles) that will have module id `main`.